# Why "<some string>" >= <a number> is TRUE?

Tags: r

Maybe it is a silly question but playing with subsetting I faced this thing and I can't understand why it happens.
For example let's consider a string, say `"a"`, and an integer, say `3`, why this expression returns `TRUE`?

```
"a" >= 3
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you try to compare a string to an integer, R will coerce the number into a string, so `3` becomes `"3"`.

Using logical operators on strings will check if the condition is true or false given their alphabetical order. For example:

```
> "a" < "b"
[1] TRUE
> "b" > "c"
[1] FALSE
```

This results happen because for R, the ascending order is `a, b, c`. Numbers usually come before letters in alphabetical orders (just check files ordered by name which start with a number). This is why you get

```
"a" >= 3
[1] TRUE
```

Finally, note that your result can vary depending on your locale and how the alphabetical order is defined on it. [The manual says](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Comparison.html):

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the
>   strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see
>   locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally
>   different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising.
>   Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in
>   Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily
>   character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after
>   z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it
>   follows g. Some platforms may not respect the locale and always sort
>   in numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in Unicode
>   code-point order for a UTF-8 locale (and may not sort in the same
>   order for the same language in different character sets). Collation of
>   non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens, fractions and so on)
>   is even more problematic.

This is important and should be considered if the logical operators are used to compare strings (regardless of comparing them to numbers or not).