# How does R compare version strings with the inequality operators?

Tags: r

Could someone explain this behavior in R?

```
> '3.0.1' < '3.0.2'
[1] TRUE

> '3.0.1' > '3.0.2'
[1] FALSE
```

What process is R doing to make the comparison?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270896/why-some-string-a-number-is-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's making a lexicographic comparison in this case, as opposed to converting to numeric, as calling `as.numeric('3.0.1')` returns `NA`.

The logic here would be something like, "the strings '3.0.1' and '3.0.2' are equivalent until their final characters, and since 1 precedes 2 in an alphanumeric alphabet, '3.0.1' is less than '3.0.2'." You can test this with some toy examples:

```
'a' < 'b' # TRUE
'ab' < 'ac' # TRUE
'ab0' < 'ab1' # TRUE
```

Per the note in the manual in the post that @rawr linked in the comments, this will get hairy in different locales, where the alphanumeric alphabet may be sorted differently.